# How to store the result of ajax call returns json into a variable?

Tags: jquery, json

How can I replace this json code :

```
var contacts = [
    { firstName: 'Mohammed', lastName: 'Shurrab', phone: '0599000000' },
    { firstName: 'Osama', lastName: 'Abu Kmail', phone: '0599111111' },
    { firstName: 'Alaa', lastName: 'Saqer', phone: '0599666666' }
];
```

with a result from jquery ajax call ( getJson ) to the following url which returns json :

```
amerenaya.com/CI/index.php/hello/example5
```

and store the result in the variable contacts?

to use in a javascript code?

Comment: make certain your response data follows the formatting rules for JSON or it will fail silently for getJSON. You can test your JSON object in jslint.com (which will tell you why it's not properly formatted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var contacts;

$.getJSON('http://amerenaya.com/CI/index.php/hello/example5').success(function(data) {
    contacts = eval(data);
});
```

Comment: If it is properly formatted JSON (which the OP's is not) you shouldn't have to run eval as it getJSON does so for you.

Comment: Right, its not properly formatted. If it was properly formatted then you would have a callback function added to the URL and everything else would work great.

Comment: it will not work because of cross domain policy

Comment: I would imagine if this individual is developing it on their own then the cross domain policy wouldn't be an issue...